# ASPx GridView row cell counter isn't giving me the right cell

Tags: c#, asp.net, aspxgridview

### EDIT

The cell count on `e.Row.Cells.Count` is indicating 6 cells instead of the 3 that I've defined. Again, wtf?

### Original Question

I've done this many times before but now I'm getting weird errors...

So what I'm trying to do is set up a javascript confirmation box to appear and prompt the user to confirm deleting a record. I do this by cast the Delete CommandField control to a LinkButton and modifying the `OnClientClick` value:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gvItems" 
    DataKeyNames="Id" 
    PageSize="20"
    OnRowDataBound="gvItems_RowDataBound"
    OnRowDeleting="gvItems_RowDeleting"
    OnSorting="gvItems_Sorting"
    OnPageIndexChanging="gvItems_PageIndexChanging"
    OnSelectedIndexChanging="gvItems_SelectedIndexChanging">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Feature Description" SortExpression="Description" />
        <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="true" SelectText="<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></i>" />
        <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="true" DeleteText="<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></i>" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Here's the C# code:

```
protected void gvItems_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType != DataControlRowType.DataRow) return;

    var btn = e.Row.Cells[e.Row.Cells.Count - 1].Controls[0] as LinkButton;
    btn.OnClientClick = "return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this feature?');";
}
```

Using `e.Row.Cells.Count - 1` to target the cell, the control it returns is a Checkbox (???????)

If I change this to use `e.Row.Cells.Count` instead, now I'm getting an ArgumentOutOfRangeException.

What's frustrating about this is that it works in another project as written above so I really haven't got the first clue where these errors are coming from.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Note that `AutoGenerateColumns` is not specified on the GridView.

The problem here is that the GridView defaults this property to true if you don't specify a value for.

This caused the column count to double so either way I tried I was always targeting the wrong column.

Solution was to explicitly set AutoGenerateColumns to false.